# Can I ask using my first/native language?

Tags: support, languages

Can I use my native language (**Malay**) to ask or answer a question at Ask Ubuntu?

Is there any volunteer to translate my answer/question?

**Bahasa Malaysia**

> Adakah boleh saya menggunakan bahasa malaysia untuk bertanya dan
>   menjawab di AskUbuntu.
>
> Ada atau tidak sukarelawan untuk menterjemah soalan dan jawapan saya?

Comment: related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3105/if-a-question-is-written-in-a-non-english-language-with-an-english-translation-p?rq=1

Comment: thanks @fossfreedom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is google's translation of your native text-

> Do can I use language to ask and answer malaysia in AskUbuntu.
>
> Whether or not volunteer to translate the questions and my answers?

Just saying that if you post in another language, users usually just "google" it. And it is usually not very good at it.

Also even if your question is translated people will not translate the questions back to your language.

Google's re-translation of this message, probally really messed up-

> Ini adalah terjemahan google ibunda teks-
>
> ```
> Adakah saya boleh menggunakan bahasa untuk bertanya dan menjawab malaysia AskUbuntu.
>
> Sama ada atau tidak sukarela untuk menterjemahkan soalan dan jawapan saya?
> ```
>
> Hanya mengatakan bahawa jika anda pos dalam bahasa lain, pengguna
>   biasanya hanya "google". Dan ia biasanya tidak sangat baik pada ia.
>
> Juga walaupun soalan anda diterjemahkan orang tidak akan
>   menterjemahkan soalan kembali kepada bahasa anda.
>
> Google terjemahan semula mesej ini, probally benar-benar merosakkan
>   sehingga-

As you can see even your orginal message seems to get distorted when translated back to you, and this is not an efficient way of communication.

So if you know the language, feel free to make an improved translation, and elect your self for translation duty, otherwise the questions is likely to be closed due to the fact that no one can understand each other.