# Editing: leave OP's original language

Tags: discussion, editing, languages

I was going to edit [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214349/cant-login-with-nautilus-sftp#1214349). My first thought was to delete the portion with the native language that OP posted. Googling it, it seems to be Norwegian. He provided a translation, that I was going to format to quotes.

But then I thought that maybe some other Norwegian would look up the same error in her/his native language.

Being this site English only, and having in mind that OP provides a translation, what is the recommendation in these cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a question is written in a non-English language with an English translation provided should the non-English part be removed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3105/if-a-question-is-written-in-a-non-english-language-with-an-english-translation-p) Also this is very related: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1506/what-to-do-with-non-english-questions-or-answers

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks, my internet is reaaally slow, so I didn't catch that question. I'll follow [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3116/931617).